# insert multiple elements to list at position

Tags: python

Is there a way to insert multiple elements to a list during a list comprehension in python?

For example:

```
def a():
   return [6,7,8]
[a() if i==2 else i for i in range(4)]
[0, 1, [6, 7, 8], 3]
```

Would it be possible to get a flat list in one go (function a could return the data in any format).

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems a bit nasty but will work with various datatypes:

```
import itertools
def a():
   return [6,7,8]
l = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([a() if i==2 else [i] for i in range(4)]))
print(l)

>>>[0, 1, 6, 7, 8, 3]
```

We can see this also works with other return types from `a`:

```
def a():
   return {6,7,8}

>>>[0, 1, 8, 6, 7, 3]
```

This is already complex enough where I would question going with a one liner approach. It's probably more readable to break this down more.

Answer (score 1):

```
def a(): return [6,7,8]
l = [a() if i==2 else [i] for i in range(4)]
flat = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
```

You could also do it *in one go* if you combine the last two lines, but that wouldn't be very pythonic.